# How to convert the list to the year

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe:

```
Name                  Year 
DC_FY19.csv            [19]
NC_FY18.csv            [18]
AK_FY18_of_19.csv      [18,19]
```

I have used a regular expressions to get the year.

```
df['Year'] = df.Name.apply(lambda x: re.findall(re'[0-9]+',x)
```

Is there a way to get a year into 2019, 2018 format.

Comment: do you want the year to always start after 2000?

Comment: Wait, what is stored in the second columns: lists of numbers, lists of strings, or strings?

Comment: @CaptainLevi is starts after 2000. i would like to keep just year not list. is there a better way do it without storing in list format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the assumption that all your years will be in 2000 and also assuming that you want to keep it as list, you can use the following code:

```
df['Year'] = df.Name.apply(lambda x: list(map(lambda x: "20"+x, re.findall('[0-9]+',x))))

Out:
                Name          Year
0        DC_FY19.csv        [2019]
1        NC_FY18.csv        [2018]
2  AK_FY18_of_19.csv  [2018, 2019]
```

If you want it as string and not as list then use the following:

```
df['Year'] = df.Name.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(map(lambda x: "20"+x, re.findall('[0-9]+',x))))

Out:
                Name        Year
0        DC_FY19.csv        2019
1        NC_FY18.csv        2018
2  AK_FY18_of_19.csv  2018, 2019
```

Comment: I was trying to parse the year from the name. yes it always starts from 20. i would like to keep only year not the list.

Comment: comma separated in case of multiple years ? @gannu

Comment: Yes that's what i was looking for.

Comment: @gannu I have updated my answer to store it as string instead of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Storing a list in a DataFrame is usually not a winning idea, but since you already do that, just add 2000 to each year:

```
df.Year.apply(lambda years: [2000+year for year in years])
#0          [2019]
#1          [2018]
#2    [2018, 2019]
```

If the years are strings, not numbers (it is not clear from your example), use string arithmetic instead:

```
df.Year.apply(lambda years: ["20"+year for year in years])
#0          [2019]
#1          [2018]
#2    [2018, 2019]
```

Finally, if you have a column of strings, use direct replacement:

```
df.Year.replace('(\d\d)', r'20\1', regex=True)
#0         [2019]
#1         [2018]
#2    [2018,2019]
```